# Width and height different in CSS and HTML

Tags: css, layout, html

Say I have a `div`. If I give it a height and width of 500*500px in HTML code, like this: `<div width="500px" height="500px">test</div>` it will not have dimensions of 500*500px unless it's filled with enough code/text to push it to those dimensions. However, if I set the exact same width and height with CSS (either inline CSS or external document) like this: `<div style="width:500px; height:500px;">test</div>` the dimensions are always what I set.

Why is there a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this isn't valid syntax. You cant add width & height attributes to a DIV the same as you can to a table or an image tag.

```
<div width="500px" height="500px">test</div>
```

This is valid syntax:

```
<div style="width:500px; height:500px;">test</div>
```

Comment: Simple answer for a simple question, can't believe I even forgot that. Thank you! Accepting answer in 12 mins (SO rules)

Comment: No worries. Also, you wouldn't be adding the "px" in regular HTML.

Answer (score 2):

A `div` tag does not have the attributes `width` and `height`.